# Building a progressive query in Mongoose based on user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm writing a simple REST API that is basically just a wrapper around a Mongo DB.   I usually like to use the following query params for controlling the query (using appropriate safeguards, of course).

- `_filter=<field_a>:<value_a>,<field_b><value_b>`

  - some values can be prepended with `<` or `>` for integer greater-than/less-than comparison
- `_sort=<field_c>:asc,<field_d>:desc`
- `_fields=<field_a>,<field_b>,<field_c>`
- `_skip=<num>`
- `_limit=<num>`

Anyway, the implementation details on these are not that important, just to show that there's a number of different ways we want to affect the query.

So, I coded the 'filter' section something like this (snipping out many of the validation parts, just to get to point):

```
    case "filter":
       var filters = req.directives[k].split(',');
       var filterObj = {};
       for(var f in filters) {
         // field validation happens here...
         splitFields = filters[f].split(':');
         if (/^ *>/.test(splitFields[1])) {
           filterObj[splitFields[0]] = {$gt: parseInt(splitFields[1].replace(/^ *>/, ''), 10)};
         }
         else if (/^ *</.test(splitFields[1])) {
           filterObj[splitFields[0]] = {$lt: parseInt(splitFields[1].replace(/^ *</, ''), 10)};
         }
         else {
           filterObj[splitFields[0]] = splitFields[1];
         }
       }
       req.directives.filter = filterObj;
       break;
       // Same for sort, fields, etc...
```

So, by the end, I have an object to pass into `.find()`.  The issue I'm having, though, is that the `$gt` gets changed into `'$gt'` as soon as it's saved as a JS object key.

Does this look like a reasonable way to go about this?  How do I get around mongoose wanting keys like `$gt` or `$lt`, and Javascript wanting to quote them?

Comment: There's no difference between `{$gt: 1}` and `{'$gt': 1}` in JavaScript, so I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into it more.  But it seemed to just ignore the '$gt': 1, filter, so I figured it was because of the key.